# Show that if , $0 \le a \le b$ , then $\|a\| \le \|b\|$

Tags: operator-theory, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

Let $A$ be a $C^{*}$-algebra. If $0 \le a \le b$, then $\|a\| \le 
\|b\|$.

We may suppose that $A$ is unital. Then, let $B=C^*({1,b})$ be the $C^*$ algebra generated by $1$ and $b$. Then the Gelfand representation $$\phi : B \to C_0(\Omega(B)), \phi(b)=\hat{b}$$ is an isometric $*$-isomorphism.

Then $\hat{b}({\tau})=\tau(b) \ge 0$ since $b \ge 0$. Then $\|b\|=\
|\hat{b}\|=\sup_{\|\tau\|=1}\tau(b) \ge \tau(b)$.
 Thus $\tau(\|b\|-b) \ge 0$ This happens for all $\tau \in \Omega(B)$. But $$\sigma_{B}(\|b\|-b)=\sigma_A(\|b\|-b)=\{\tau(\|b\|-b): \tau \in \Omega(B)\}$$
Hence $\sigma_{B}(\|b\|-b) \subset R^{+}$. So $b \le \|b\|$ which gives that $a  \le \|b\| $.

Now Let $C$ be the $C^*$-algebra generated by ${1,a}$. Then the Gelfand representation $$\psi : C \to C_0(\Omega(C)), \phi(a)=\hat{a}$$ is an isometric $*$-isomorphism.
 Then $||a||=||\hat{a}||=\sup_{||\tau||=1}(\tau(a)) \le \sup_{||\tau||=1}\tau(||b||) \le ||b||$

I am kind of confused here. What is the need of turning to Gelfand Representation for this ??

Is this right enough??

Thanks for the help!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's one way to prove it. Hard to avoid some machinery, I guess.

A shorter proof can be achieved by representing $A$ faithfully in some $B(H)$. Then $\langle a\xi,\xi\rangle\leq\langle b\xi,\xi\rangle$ for any $\xi\in H$, and so 
$$
\|a\|=\sup\{\langle a\xi,\xi\rangle:\ \xi\in H,\ \|\xi\|=1\}
\leq \sup\{\langle b\xi,\xi\rangle:\ \xi\in H,\ \|\xi\|=1\}=\|b\|.
$$